# Are combinations of independent random variables also independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I have three i.i.d. random variables: X, Y and Z.
I have two constants: c1 and c2.

Is it true that: Pr[Y-X < c1 AND Z-X < c2] = Pr[Y-X < c1] * Pr[Z-X < c2]?

I am guessing that this only holds when Y-X and Z-X are independent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Right, which leads me to think the answer to my original question is "yes". But I'm not entirely convinced why: Specifically, when X is a random variable, its value seems to be affecting both Pr[Y-X] and Pr[Z-X]. E.g., when X is high, both Pr[Y-X<c1] and Pr[Z-X<c2] are low. Then I'm confused: Y-X and Z-X don't seem independent to me, and I shouldn't be able to separate the joint probability. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The only way I can understand your hint, it is very misleading. Do you suggest that one should show that $P(Y<a+X,Z<b+X)=P(Y<a+X)P(Z<b+X)$ (which is quite wrong, except perhaps in a few degenerate cases)? If not, what? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition if $Y-X$ and $Z-X$ are independent,
$$
P( (Y-X < c_1) \wedge (Z-X < c_2) ) = P(Y-X < c_1) \cdot P(Z-X < c_2)
$$

But with $\{X, Y, Z\}$ i.i.d. random variables, it is hard to find an underlying distribution such that  $Y-X$ and $Z-X$ are independent.  In fact, the only case where this would be true would be if the underlying distribution has all its probability at one value!

To show that $Y-X$ and $Z-X$ need not be independent,
consider $\{X, Y, Z\}$ to be independent uniform randoms on $(0,1)$.

Then take $c_1 = +0.9$ and $c_2 = -0.2$.  Now whenever $Y-X < c_1$ is false, $Z-X < c_2$ must also be false.  Since neither of those statements are always false, in this case  $Y-X$ and $Z-X$ are not independent.

Comment: OK, good example, so Y-X and Z-X are not independent. Does this imply Pr[Y-X < c1 AND Z-X < c2] is NOT equal to Pr[Y-X < c1] * Pr[Z-X < c2]? In the comments to the original question, Yves seems to suggest the two are indeed equal.

Comment: @user274179 Yeah, the comment you are referring to is horribly misleading.